# variable undefined in inner query in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm new in laravel, and I have a problem in the controller..
I need to retrieve one row from a table that specified my condition, then I need to join the result with two tables.
I try to write this code, but I have this error [ Undefined variable: coursenum ]

```
public function stafflogin (Request $request) {$jobid=$request->input('jobID');
$coursenum=$request->input('referenceNumber');
$semester=$request->input('semester');
$checklogin=DB::table('members')->select('jobID')->where(['jobID'=>$jobid])->get();
```

this is the query:

```
if(count($checklogin)>0){ $users=DB::table('members_courses_assign')->join('members','members.externalPersonKey','=','members_courses_assign.externalPersonKey')
   ->whereIn('referenceNumber', function($query)
   {
       $query->select(DB::raw(1))
             ->from('courses')
             ->where(['referenceNumber'=>$coursenum,'termkey'=>$semester])->get();
   })
  ->where(['jobID'=>$jobid]) ->get();
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please pretend for a moment that you are one of us. Could you answer this question based on the information you provide us here?

Comment: At the very least show the code you've written, how you're executing it, your expected outcome and the error you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please insert code not an image !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please try something like this :

```
->whereIn('referenceNumber', function($query) use ($coursenum, $semestre)
{
        // put yout code here     
})
```